# Error while partitioning. [Err] 1654 - Partition column values of incorrect type

Tags: mysql

What's wrong with this MySQL query?
Result is `[Err] 1654 - Partition column values of incorrect type`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS part;
CREATE TABLE `part` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cnt` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `created`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS (created)(
    PARTITION p_2015_01 VALUES LESS THAN ('2015-01-30') ENGINE=InnoDB,
    PARTITION p_2015_02 VALUES LESS THAN ('2015-02-30') ENGINE=InnoDB,
    PARTITION p_2015_03 VALUES LESS THAN ('2015-03-30') ENGINE=InnoDB,
    PARTITION p_catchall VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) ENGINE=InnoDB
);
```

If it matters, the version is 5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took quite a long time to see the obvious:

**The date '2015-02-30' does not exist.**

Presumably it is converted to NULL or something, therefore the message about 'incorrect type'.

Hopefully it helps somebody someday.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the online-schema-change tool from the Percona toolkit to reorganize partitions, you can also get this error for using single quotes around an alter containing single quotes. Silly, but I just ran into it.

```
root@host:~# pt-online-schema-change --execute --no-drop-old-table --progress='time,1' --recursion-method=none  --alter='REORGANIZE PARTITION pMAXVALUE INTO ( PARTITION p20161206 VALUES LESS THAN ('2016-12-06'),PARTITION pMAXVALUE VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE))' D=somedb,t=sometable
```

vs

```
root@host:~# pt-online-schema-change --execute --no-drop-old-table --progress='time,1' --recursion-method=none  --alter="REORGANIZE PARTITION pMAXVALUE INTO ( PARTITION p20161206 VALUES LESS THAN ('2016-12-06'),PARTITION pMAXVALUE VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE))" D=somedb,t=sometable
```

Answer (score 0):

An example of a variant that may lead to a similar error [#HY000 Partition column values of incorrect type]:

create table if not exists tbl (
col     varchar(10))
partition by list columns (col)(
    partition blablablabla values in ('blablablabla')
);

If length('blablablabla')  > to the size specified in the column col (varchar(10)) we will get this error. In my case, increasing the max length of the characters of that specific column solve the issue.